# pandas .12 working but .13 has error when df.index is passed a series

Tags: python, pandas

Why doesn't this code work in version pandas .13?  is it a bug or do i need to do things differently?

```
previous=0
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    if i in df.index[df.groupby(['case']).apply(lambda x: x['change'].idxmin())]:
      print 'anything'
```

i can't find any documentation that shows why.

for testing

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
d = {'case' : pd.Series([1,1,1,1,2]),
'open' : pd.Series([DT.datetime(2014, 3, 2), DT.datetime(2014, 3, 2),DT.datetime(2014, 3, 2),DT.datetime(2014, 3, 2),DT.datetime(2014, 3, 2)]),
'change' : pd.Series([DT.datetime(2014, 3, 8), DT.datetime(2014, 4, 8),DT.datetime(2014, 5, 8),DT.datetime(2014, 6, 8),DT.datetime(2014, 6, 8)]),
'StartEvent' : pd.Series(['Homeless','Homeless','Homeless','Homeless','Jail']),
'ChangeEvent' : pd.Series(['Homeless','irrelivant','Homeless','Jail','Jail']),
'close' : pd.Series([DT.datetime(2015, 3, 2), DT.datetime(2015, 3, 2),DT.datetime(2015, 3, 2),DT.datetime(2015, 3, 2),DT.datetime(2015, 3, 2)])}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very odd to do it this way, what would you expect the result to be?

If you really really want to do this, use the value. A Series is not a valid indexer to `df.index` (only an array is). This 'worked' in 0.12, but happened to rely on the fact that a Series was an ndarray sub-class.

```
df.index[df.groupby(['case']).apply(lambda x: x['change'].idxmin()).values]
Int64Index([0, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I have a whole lot of conditions to work into an equation and thought it would be easier to read in for and if statements.  thanks for helping

Comment: it is very obvious when i look at your clean code!  thanks, really.